# PHP FOREACH ARRAY problem

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, foreach

This is what I have:

```
$prevtag = "1,2,5";

$arr;
$arr["1"] = "BOOKS";
$arr["2"] = "MAGAZINES";
$arr["3"] = "PAMPHLETS";
$arr["4"] = "CD'S";
$arr["5"] = "DVD'S";
```

And I need to check if any of $prevtag exists in $arr and then echo 5 checkboxes:

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    $checked = in_array($prevtag,$arr) ? '' : 'checked="checked"';
    echo "<input name=\"txtTags".$key."\" type=\"checkbox\" id=\"txtTags".$key."\" value=\"on\" $checked />\n";
    echo "<label for=\"txtTags".$key."\">".$value."</label>\n";
}
```

But I'm getting all checked and not just the ones in $prevtag - What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`in_array($prevtag,$arr)` is checking if the array `$arr` contains value `1,2,5`

so you can do this:

```
$checked = in_array($key, explode(',', $prevtag)) ? '' : 'checked="checked"';
```

Answer (score 2):

In your example `$prevtag` is a string and not an array so you cannot use `in_array()` on it.

So you can try:

```
$prevtag = explode(',', $prevtag);
```

And then:

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    $checked = in_array($key, $prevtag) ? '' : 'checked="checked"';
    echo "<input name=\"txtTags".$key."\" type=\"checkbox\" id=\"txtTags".$key."\" value=\"on\" $checked />\n";
    echo "<label for=\"txtTags".$key."\">".$value."</label>\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$checked = strpos( $prevtag, (string)$key ) ? '' : 'checked="checked"';
```

$prevtag is string not array -> `in_array()` would not apply

Answer (score 1):

Make `$prevtag` an array and do something like this

```
$preArray=explode(",",$prevtag);

foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    $checked = in_array($key,$preArray) ? 'checked="checked"' : '';
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are checking if '1,2,5' is inside 'books' or 'magazines' etc

```
$prevtag = array(1,2,5);
$checked = in_array($key, $prevtag) ? 'checked="checked"' : ''
```